# Bulk insert in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, cte, bulk-insert

I have two tables on which I perform some bulk inserts:

1. key: key_id (pk), key_name
2. related_key: related_key_id (pk), key_id (fk)

First `INSERT`:

```
values_data = "($$key_1$$), ($$key_2$$)"

INSERT INTO key (key_name) VALUES values_data
```

Sec `INSERT`:

```
values_data = "(1, `the id of the first value inserted in key`)
             , (1, `the id of the sec value inserted in key`)"

INSERT INTO related_key (related_key_id, key_id) VALUES values_data
```

I don't know how to do the second `INSERT` because I don't know how to get those ids for the rows inserted in the `key` table.

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [**data-modifying CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to chain the inserts in a single statement.

Assuming from your example that you want to insert `1` for `related_key_id` in all rows.

```
WITH ins_key AS (
   INSERT INTO key (key_name)
   VALUES ($$key_1$$)
        , ($$key_2$$)
   RETURNING key_id       -- return newly generated key_id(s)
   )
INSERT INTO related_key (related_key_id, key_id) 
SELECT 1, key_id
FROM   ins_key;
```