# How to INSERT INTO ... RETURNING for matrices in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select

Approximate size and type of `c_matrix_data` is 2k x 3k double which is equivalent max to `rand(5000,5000)` in Matlab 2016b. 
The random set selection of such data corresponds max 1 GB size (so `BYTEA` ok) for many measurements, presenting about 5% of all measurements. 
Queries to CREATE and INSERT bulk with `RETURNING`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS measurements, c_matrices;    
CREATE TABLE measurements (
        measurement_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        db_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        patient_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        channel_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        c_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_measurements UNIQUE (time),
        CONSTRAINT no_same_measurements UNIQUE (db_id, patient_id, channel_id, c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE c_matrices (
        c_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        measurement_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        event_index_start INTEGER NOT NULL,
        event_index_end INTEGER NOT NULL,
        c_matrix_data BYTEA NOT NULL,
        c_size_in_bytes INTEGER NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end)
);

-- http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107062/69807
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO measurements (measurement_id, db_id, patient_id, channel_id) -- TODO not sure since this autogenerated
   VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4) -- if data comes from client app
   -- SELECT ... if data from other db TODO  how to do this here SELECT c_id FROM c_matrices WHERE measurement_id==777 
   RETURNING measurement_id  -- generating a serial ID
   )
INSERT INTO c_matrices (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end, c_matrix_data, c_size_in_bytes)
    VALUES (1, 2, 3, 'testBinaryData', 1234) 
    RETURNING c_id -- generating a serial id -- TODO right?
    FROM   ins1;
```

I run `psql data -f creates.sql` and get where the error comes from `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING`

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
psql:creates.sql:38: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 10: FROM   ins1;
```

PostgreSQL: 9.4
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Client application: Matlab 2016b
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: So 100M data points per measurement? How many of those do you want to store? Also, how do you plan to query them?

Comment: @dezso I want to store 1-5% of them for internal quality assurance. There is now the CREATE of tables. - - This field is open `matrix_data double TODO      | NOT NULL`. What do you think?

Comment: @dezso I plan to use `RETURNING` in querying the database. What do you think? Please, see the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, though I have to wonder if this isn't a better match for PostGIS's raster, or another tool entirely.

```
INSERT INTO c_matrices (measurement_id, event_index_start, event_index_end, c_matrix_data, c_size_in_bytes)
    VALUES (1, 2, 3, 'testBinaryData', 1234) 
    RETURNING c_id -- generating a serial id -- TODO right?
    FROM   ins1;
```

Not sure what this is supposed to do. To have a `FROM` you must have a `SELECT`, `RETURNING` comes *after* `FROM`. Close though.

```
-- Sample data.
# CREATE TABLE foo (id serial, b int);

-- Demo
# INSERT INTO foo (b) SELECT 42 RETURNING id;
 id 
----
  1
(1 row)
```

Comment: What would be your approach with PostGIS's raster?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Create a raster 2k x 3k double, and populate it. PostGIS has MapAlgebra functions and the like that you can run on the raster. It depends on what kinds of searching and indexing you're doing, but a raster is essentially a matrix under the hood: a visual representation of data.