# How do I return all column values for the recently inserted row/rows?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, cte

I have these two tables in a PostgreSQL 12 database:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    entity_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
);

CREATE TABLE public.test_registration (
    entity_id uuid REFERENCES test(entity_id),
    row_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    entry_name text,
    code text
);
```

`entry_name` is populated by a trigger `AFTER INSERT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_registration_entry_name()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE test_registration
   SET entry_name = new_inserts.code
   FROM new_inserts
   WHERE new_inserts.row_id = test_registration.row_id;
   RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON test_registration
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_inserts
FOR EACH STATEMENT
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_registration_entry_name();
```

The trigger function differs from table to table.

My current issue is when I insert a row into `test_registration` as such:

```
INSERT INTO test DEFAULT VALUES
RETURNING entity_id;  -- let's say: 'a17e66c5-1049-4ba9-bed3-90bbc823e064'
```

And then insert a registration and return all row values for the inserted row:

```
INSERT INTO test_registration (entity_id,code)
VALUES ('a17e66c5-1049-4ba9-bed3-90bbc823e064'::uuid,'EB')
RETURNING *
```

I get all column values correctly, except for the `entry_name` which is null. Which makes sense because `entry_name` is being set *after* the insert.

So I tried to expose this by altering my `INSERT` using the `row_id` as such:

```
WITH create_query AS (INSERT INTO test_registration (entity_id,code)
VALUES ('a17e66c5-1049-4ba9-bed3-90bbc823e064'::uuid,'13')
RETURNING *) SELECT v.entity_id, v.row_id, b.entity_id,b.entry_name, b.row_id 
from create_query AS v, test_registration AS b WHERE V.Row_id = b.Row_id
```

This then turns out to not return anything. `create_query.row_id` seems to differ from the one in `test_registration` - which makes no sense? Why would they be different?

How can I extract all column values for the inserted row, after the triggers has been triggered.

Answer (score 1):

#### Impossible with an `AFTER` trigger

The version of the row visible to the `RETURNING` clause is the same version that's visible to an `AFTER` trigger. The `UPDATE` in your trigger function creates a new row version. It's impossible to see the effects in the `RETURNING` clause, which is based on the prior row version. Demo:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e358fd26c98aa0f03655d3c4b20be24f)*

Effectively, the output of `RETURNING` is "dead on arrival", obsoleted immediately by the `AFTER` trigger. You would need a separate `SELECT` to see the new row version. (Can be in the same transaction.)

#### Impossible with a CTE

Your query is bound to return nothing:

```
WITH create_query AS (
   INSERT INTO test_registration (entity_id,code)
   VALUES ('a17e66c5-1049-4ba9-bed3-90bbc823e064'::uuid,'13')
   RETURNING *
   )
SELECT v.entity_id, v.row_id, b.entity_id, b.entry_name, b.row_id 
FROM   create_query AS v, test_registration AS b
WHERE  v.row_id = b.row_id;
```

All sub-statements of a query with CTEs see the same snapshot of the database. Since the `SELECT` cannot yet see the row inserted in the CTE (and `row_id` is populated with `uuid_generate_v4()`) your implicit `JOIN` is bound to return *no row*.

See:

- [Why can't rows inserted in a CTE be updated in the same statement?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151199/why-cant-rows-inserted-in-a-cte-be-updated-in-the-same-statement/151217#151217)

#### Proper trigger

I see nothing to warrant a `STATEMENT`-level, nor the need for an `AFTER` trigger. Use a much simpler (and faster) `ROW`-level trigger `BEFORE`. Then `RETURNING *` will just work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_registration_entry_name()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.entry_name := NEW.code;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER test_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON test_registration
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0
      AND NEW.entry_name IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.code) -- optional
EXECUTE FUNCTION test_registration_entry_name();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e8aa2bc957c6cc481abb55d79d2b197d)*

(The fiddle operates with integers because the additional module [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) providing `uuid_generate_v4()` is not installed on dbfiddle.uk. But it works all the same.)

I added another (optional) trigger condition: `NEW.entry_name IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.code` to avoid needless work if the trigger wouldn't change anything.

Related:

- [Assign to NEW by key in a Postgres trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82039/assign-to-new-by-key-in-a-postgres-trigger/82044#82044)

#### Aside: more efficient `INSERT`

Do both inserts in a single query with a data-modifying CTE like this:

```
WITH ins_test AS (
   INSERT INTO test DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING entity_id
   )
INSERT INTO test_registration (entity_id, code)
SELECT entity_id, 'EB'
FROM   ins_test
RETURNING *;
```

Then you can immediately reuse the auto-generated `entity_id` without another round-trip to the server. See:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561627/939860)
- [Bulk insert in multiple tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75210/bulk-insert-in-multiple-tables/75218#75218)
- [Conditional INSERT with a nested CTE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203258/conditional-insert-with-a-nested-cte/203269#203269)

Comment: Hmmm... The trigger itself it executed AFTER INSERT, Is there really no way around it?

Comment: @kafka: The statement you show is broken by design as explained. (Also demonstrated in the fiddle I added.) But there is a much better solution for the trigger, which obviates the need for a workaround.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate explanation, but I do need `for each statement` for the trigger as some of the inserts can consist of doing inserts of multiple rows, hence making this performance inefficient if the the trigger is executed for foreach row. 

I tried changing my `AFTER` insert to `BEFORE` but got into some issues with not able to reference table?

Comment: The question did not specify that constraint. I can only work with what's disclosed. (Also, my trigger should be more efficient for "multiple rows", too.) Transition tables are only possible with `AFTER` triggers.